# nested ajax and xml parsing

Tags: xml, ajax, parsing, nested

While making a nested Ajax call, how do I pass the index of the first loop to the second loop?

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url1",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml (xml){

    $title = $(xml).find("title");
    //find every Tutorial and print the author
    $title.each(function(index)
    {
        //alert($(this).text());
        if (index != 0) {
            $("#container").append('<div id=' + index + '></div>');
            $('#' + index).text($(this).text());
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(xml).find('content').eq(index).attr('src'),
                dataType: "xml",
                async: false,
                success: parseInnerXml(index3)
            });
        }
    });

}

function innerXml(xml2, index3)
{
    // is this how i get the value of index3
    // also will xml2 contain the new xml doc ..
}
```

Comment: `$title = $(xml).find("title");` needs to be `var $title = $(xml).find("title");`, otherwise you're writing to a global `$title` variable...

Comment: A side tip: Never set an `id` of an element to a value that's **not** a proper javascript variable name. Ever. It's not only bad practice but it'll garbage the DOM namespace in some browsers. Either prefix it and parse out the prefixing later or simply set a custom attribute (preferably namespaced) and select based on that later.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @alpha123 that you should make `$title` local to the `parseXml` function by using `var $title` instead.

I'm guessing that `index3` is a typo and that you want to use `index` in the `parseInnerXml` function. So you must create a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) that captures the `index` value. The `createParseInnerXmlCallback` function will do this.

```
function parseXml (xml){
    function createParseInnerXmlCallback(index) {
        return function () {
            parseInnerXml(index);
        }
    }

    var $title = $(xml).find("title");

    //find every Tutorial and print the author
    $title.each(function(index)
    {
        //alert($(this).text());
        if (index != 0) {
            $("#container").append('<div id=' + index + '></div>');
            $('#' + index).text($(this).text());
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(xml).find('content').eq(index).attr('src'),
                dataType: "xml",
                async: false,
                success: createParseInnerXmlCallback(index)
            });
        }
    });
}
```